javascript setting a .map() range and update the range later
I'm building an app with React & JS which returns products from a json list inside a component, the array is outputted on the app using a .map() array. I'm also limiting the amount to return initially in the map using a .slice(0, 30) to return the first 30 products.
However I also want to be able to update the range on the click of a button later to then load 60 products (include the next 30 products with the original 30):
products.slice(0, 60).map(product => (......));

(products. is just the variable that is storing the json array in my code)
I don't know if there's a way to update or reload a map with the new slice amount, or if there's a better way than using .slice() to do this?
I tried adding a click event to a button which runs a function that updates a variable containing the max number of products to return let numberOfProductsToShow  = 30 that takes the original number and adds 30 numberOfProductsToShow = numberOfProductsToShow + 30; and then running the same function again with the updated max value passed to the slice .slice(0, numberOfProductsToShow).
    const productList = document.querySelector('.productsList .products');
    productList.innerHTML = propductsMap(0, numberOfProductsToShow);

but this just returns the words [object Object],[object Object],[object Ob...etc 60 times so that's obviously not correct.
More code as requested for initial reopening:


import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import productData from './assets/products.json'

const App = () => {

  const [products, setProducts] = useState([])
  
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setProducts(productData.products);
  })
  
  let numberOfProductsToShow = 30;
  
  const propductsMap = (loadFrom, loadTo) => {
    return (
      products.slice(loadFrom, loadTo).map(product => (

        <div className='product' key={product.id}>
          <div className='productImage'>
            <img src="" data-src={product.thumbnail} />
          </div>
          <div className='productInfo'>
            <div className='productTitle'>
              <div className='productBrand'>{product.brand}</div> 
              <div className='productName'>{product.title}</div>
            </div>
            <div className='productPrice'>Price: {product.price}</div>
          </div>
          
        </div>
      ))
    )
  }
  
  const viewMoreButton = document.querySelector('.viewMore button');
    const productList = document.querySelector('.productsList .products');
    viewMoreButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      loadMoreProducts();
    });

    const loadMoreProducts = () => {
      numberOfProductsToShow = numberOfProductsToShow + 30;
      productList.innerHTML = propductsMap(0, numberOfProductsToShow);
    };
    
    return (
    <div className='shopperApp'>
      <Header />

      <div className='productsList'>
        <div className='products'>
          {propductsMap(0, numberOfProductsToShow)}
        </div>        
        <div className='viewMore'><button>View More</button></div>
      </div>

      

    </div>
  )
}

export default App
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>




You could use another setState to keep track of the amount you want to show. But you should never use innerHTML in react context, just render the map result self. If you can add a small [mre] it might help.

Why is this closed right away? Decent question with OP's attempt, so 'needs debugging details' doesn't seem to fit here.

Thank you @0stone0, I'm not sure why it's been closed straight away, I couldn't find an answer after a lot of searching to the question, I thought I added the relevant bits of code and what's being outputted as an issue. I can try adding alot more mode to make it exact but didn't think it was necessary. Anyway I do have a setState already there const [products, setProducts] = useState([]) I'll try and add more to the OP but how would I update the amount of products to return using it?

Please add a [mre] so we can vote to re-open. You could use a button to call the setState of the variable that hold the amount you want to show. THen your component will rerender causing the map to update

Can you please share how you're mapping & your component? Keep in mind, when using React, it's very rare that you'll need to use DOM apis such as getElementById() or .innerHTML. The idea is that you return what you want to render from your component, and the content that you return can be dictated by state (and updates based on when you change your state).

You just need to add products.json as a variable in your code to make it runnable.

Okay I've found a kind of solution with the help above while it's still under review, I've added a limit object to my JSON, set the slice to use it's value .slice(0, productData.limit).map() and then used the setState to update it with: setProducts(productData.limit = productData.limit + 30);       console.log(productData.limit);. Which works however my apps running/console logging everything 3 times and running the setState change 6 times meaning it keeps doubling everything multiple times and not returning just the next 30 products but all of them in one click :(

I do hope this still gets reopened so you can post your answer like normal instead of editing it in the question.

@Wimanicesir yeah that would make it easier for anyone in the future to easily find the answer and I can make the the original question more efficient

The JSON file needed a Limit object and value adding along side the products list:
{
  "products": [
    {
    ...
    }
  ],
  "limit": 30

Create a second useState which stores and allows the limit value to be updated, then add that initial useState variable to the .slice() to return the initial number of products set by the JSON limit value:
const [productsLimit, setProductsLimit] = useState(productData.limit)

productData.products.slice(0, productsLimit).map(product => (
        <div className='product' key={product.id}>
          <div className='productImage'>
            <img src="" data-src={product.thumbnail} />
          </div>
          <div className='productInfo'>
            <div className='productTitle'>
              <div className='productBrand'>{product.brand}</div> 
              <div className='productName'>{product.title}</div>
            </div>
            <div className='productPrice'>Price: {product.price}</div>
          </div>
          
        </div>
      ))

Finally the button just needs to be made to update the new useState with a new value to increase the amount of products to show:
const viewMoreButton = document.querySelector('.viewMore button');
viewMoreButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  setProductsLimit(productsLimit + productData.limit);
});

Answer provided by question author.
